# Control language of facebooks open graph responses

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a request to facebook-api.
My url looks like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/XXX/events/attending/?fields=start_time&limit=100&locale=de_DE&access_token=XXX
```

The Result looks fine:

```
   "data": [
      {
         "start_time": "2017-11-18T20:00:00+0100",
         "id": "xxx"
      },
      {
         "start_time": "2017-09-29T20:00:00+0200",
         "place": {
            "name": "xxx",
            "location": {
               "city": "Cologne",
               "country": "Germany",
               "latitude": x,
               "longitude": x,
               "street": "x",
               "zip": "x"
            },
            "id": "xxx"
         },
         "id": "xxx"
      }
```

The only Problem is, that the city names are in english. I need them in german.

As you can see i already tried adding the parameter "locale=de_DE" but this doesn't change anything..

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this?

I would be really greatful because I am searching for an answer for weeks now..

Comment: locale would be the way to go, but it looks like they did not implement it for this particular situation. I’d file a bug report & ask them to fix this. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @jerg did you manage to get the city names in german? I'm still struggling with it... behindert.

Comment: Unfortunately not! It's a shame. I'll post a bug-report for this in the next days, because its getting urgent now.